# GC_* errors in my database heavy intentservice that is running every 20 seconds

Tags: java, android, sqlite, garbage-collection

It is a heavy intentservice, it has a lot, i mean alot of database query, updating,deleting, randomizing numbers.. so many.. it runs every 20seconds for TESTING PUrpoSE, the intent service will probably run every 5 mins.. but there will be instance that it may run 48 times one after the other.. what can i do to avoid this Garbage collectors error?

if i transfer half of the code to another intentservice, can it help? is it in differerent thread isnt it? will that help?.. i  closed all the cursor after it is used

Comment: Are these really `GC_*` errors or only messages in logcat informing about GC freeing memory?

Comment: yup, because it gives me the error randomly, doesnt give me any consistent error, it may run 10 times , then after, gives me error.. now im calling System.gc(); , it hasnt given me errors now, but im afraid that if i finish the whole code, (This code is only 1/4 through), it will give me a lot of GC errors

Comment: Freeing up memory, sorry

Comment: Yes, explicit calls to `System.gc()` really should work.

Comment: I think its really working wonderfully, but as i said, after more db queries, can those GC might back?.. is it better to transfer some of the code in another intent service? would that help? Also, i saw the cache of my app, its 600kb already, is that large? cause i saw others' cache in davlik, its average is 60kb

Comment: System.gc() it's not a solution actually, it doesn't run GC, it only give a "recomendation" to run GC. Moving logic to other `IntentService` wouldn't help you. Yes it runs in different thread but in the same process, so it wouldn't boost you heap size.

Comment: yes, i read that its only a reccomendation, so it means i can only recommend it, is that mean that if i request a GC, it would analyze my apps cache(or something) then act if it is better to be GC-ed?...thanks regarding about the Service

Comment: I don't have such deep knoleges about GC , BUT i'm not really understand a problem, memory is not freeing up or what? Errors is bad thing, sure, but it's just a messages. Are you leaking memory?

Comment: Its only freeing up the memory, GC_FOR_MALLOC, GC_EXPLICIT, GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC, are those i saw, it doesnt really kill the process, but it gives me "Force Closed",

Comment: @mcr619619 Forse close with exception?If yes please provide a stack trace or any other data from logcat.

Comment: how can i do that? the emulator only say FOrce close..

Comment: if yourev talking about the logcat, no exception... only after GC*, sometimes it gives me forceclose